# PHP7 does not install on Ubuntu with PPA

Tags: php, vagrant

I have a problem. I want to install PHP7 on my Ubuntu Vagrant default 64Bit Machine, using the normal method specified everywhere:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
```

However, if I `apt-cache search` for `php` or `php7`, I can't find anything there to be installed. Is it not possible to install on a Vagrant default image? Or is there just a current temporary issue with the PPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ppa:ondrej/php`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/) provides PHP packages only for only for [supported releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and usually a current development release after some reasonable time.

At the time (May 2016) of writing this, the list includes:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty)
- Ubuntu 15.10 (wily) (EOL July 2016)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial)

When you open the PPA in the browser and click on [View package details](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages) in the top right corner, it states at the top of the page:

> This PPA currently publishes packages for Xenial, Wily, Trusty and Precise.

Note: At the time of the question was asked, the support for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was not there and was added only later, hence the package not found error.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test it, but maybe that could solve the problem. I tried the default precise64 box which is not the trusty one, I think.